# Entity Error: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, entity

It's impossible for me to add an entity to my solution. I keep getting the error "***Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.***" Even in a new project under the same solution or with an empty EDMX, i get the error. Does someone have an idea what causes the error?

Thank you

Comment: It's kind of hard to help you if you don't provide the code.

Comment: I can imagine, but i didn't change anything in particular in my project for it to cause the error, so i have no idea what i have to post as code. I just created a new project, not connected to TFS and it works, so i'll just start over again. Altough it would be nice if someone encountered the same problem and could point me out what i might have done wrong.

Comment: what do you mean with 'add an entity to my solution'?

Comment: And when exactly do you get the error? What are the steps you did? What database?

Comment: I right click on my solution, add new item and in the data section i select ADO.NET Entity Data Model. When i click the add, i immidiatly get the error message "Operation is not valid due.... " and the Add New Item objectbrowsers re-opens after the error. I'm connecting to an SQL database hosted on the Azure cloud. ( I don't think it matters because i get the error with an empty EDMX also )

Comment: Hm, indeed, strange, seems that something is corrupted or so. Maybe reinstall EF?

Comment: I made a new solution and everything works fine again, altough it frustrates me when i don't know the cause of an error. Thank you for your help kind sir!

Comment: I guess that Visual Studio sometimes behaves strangely...